# How to use conditions in .gitlab-ci.yml variables?

Tags: variables, if-statement, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to know, if it's possible to set custom Gitlab CI variable from if-else condition statement.

In my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file I have the following:

```
variables:
    PROJECT_VERSION: (if [ "${CI_COMMIT_TAG}" == "" ]; then "${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}-${CI_PIPELINE_ID}"; else ${CI_COMMIT_TAG}; fi);

Trying to set project version:
    image: php:7.1-cli
    stage: test
    script:
        # this echoes correct string (eg. "master-2794")
        - (if [ "${CI_COMMIT_TAG}" == "" ]; then echo "${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}-${CI_PIPELINE_ID}"; else echo ${CI_COMMIT_TAG}; fi);
        # this echoes something like "(if [ "" == "" ]; then "master-2794"; else ; fi);"
        - echo $PROJECT_VERSION
```

Can this be done? If so, what have I missed? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

`CI_COMMIT_TAG` is only set to a value in a GitLab job. From https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html

> CI_COMMIT_TAG - The commit tag name. Present only when building tags.

Therefore in the `variables` section `CI_COMMIT_TAG` is not defined, hence equals to "".

So if you want to use `CI_COMMIT_TAG` use in job where tags are defined. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#tags

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#tags doesn't seem to be the appropriate reference, it is rather https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#only-and-except-simplified (for `only: tags`)

Answer (score 10):

It is possible:

Add your logic into the `variable` section:

```
variables:
  VERSION_LOGIC: '(if [ "$${CI_COMMIT_TAG}" == "" ]; then echo "1.3.5.$$CI_PIPELINE_IID"; else echo "$${CI_COMMIT_TAG}"; fi);'
```

Now you are able to use this logic in a script secion of a job:

```
version:
  stage: versioning
  script:
    - VERSION=$(eval $VERSION_LOGIC)
    - echo "The current version is set to ${VERSION}."
```

Comment: +1 for the creative solution. not sure if I would implement it this way, it seems much simpler to just script the logic under the `script` lines directly.